# Deploying an node app to google App engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

[image]

I succeeded deploy to google app engine but there is an error "node: --http-server-default-timeout= is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS" What this means? I don't know what to do

Comment: Do you have any `NODE_OPTIONS` set up on your environment? Can you share them?

Comment: In my web application,there is no set up about NODE_OPTIONS.

Comment: As you can see on the [NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config), the environment variable NODE_OPTIONS is used to pass options through to Node.js, maybe you have the `--http-server-default-timeout=` set in there without knowing it, I suggest you try to remove that variable from your `app.yaml`, if you indeed have no use for it, If it is not in there already try assigning it and empty value, you can check more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref), let me know if this helped.

Comment: Sorry not worked. There is no variable in `app.yaml`

Comment: Have you tried adding a `env_variables: NODE_OPTIONS: ""` to it?

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much your help. You saved me

Comment: Great, I will add it to an official answer then, please remember to accept and upvote it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you are using `--http-server-default-timeout` somewhere in the options of you app. As a workaround you can add an empty `NODE_OPTIONS` to you `app.yaml` by adding the following:

```
env_variables: 
    NODE_OPTIONS: ""
```

Keep in mind that this will overwrite any `NODE_OPTIONS` you had elsewhere.

**NOTE**: I did some investigating and found that this notation is available for Node.js after version 12.4.0 as per this [documentation](https://nodejs.org/zh-cn/blog/uncategorized/10-lts-to-12-lts/#notable-changes-in-node-js-12-4-0), so maybe the root cause of your issue is that there is some version mismatch on your runtime, dependencies or something related to that.